# Olbers' paradox and thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, stars

So consider our universe as an isolated system which has reached thermal equilibrium. Now using the first law of thermodynamics:

$$ \underbrace{T dS}_{\text{Total energy}} = \underbrace{P dV}_{\text{Energy of C.O.M}}+ \underbrace{dU}_{\text{internal energy}} $$

where $T$ is temperature, $S$ is entropy, $P$ is pressure, $V$ is volume and $U$ is the internal energy (C.O.M is the center of mass).

Then I can play the following trick:

$$ TdS = P \dot V dt + dU$$

where $\dot V = dV/dt$ where $t$ is time. Hence, in a universe during the period which the internal energy is constant.

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}|_{U} = P \frac{\dot V}{T} $$

Now, from the second law of thermodynamics we know:

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}|_{U} = P \frac{\dot V}{T} \geq 0$$

Thus, for the above to hold there are four possible possibilities:

1. The volume is constant.
2. The universe has always been in thermal equilibrium and has always had a uniform distribution.
3. The universe is expanding.

But wait recall the possible resolutions to [Olbers' paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox):

1. The universe is not infinitely old. The light from distant stars has not had enough time to reach us yet. (2)
2. The universe is not infinitely large. There are simply not enough stars in the universe (1)
   to fill the sky with light.
3. The distribution of stars is not uniform. There are large regions of space that are devoid of stars (2)
4. The universe is expanding. This means that the light from distant stars has been redshifted, making it dimmer and harder to see (3)

Given the uncanny resemblance I suspect this is a similar problem but somehow reframed?

Comment: The "four possible possibilities" doesn't make sense. If you assume constant $U$ in a derivation, you can't assume other possibilities; option (1) must hold. Furthermore, if an isolated system is at equilibrium, we already have $dS = 0$ (entropy maximization), so option (3) must hold. You've simply reiterated your assumptions for this arbitrary system; I don't see what the universe has to do with it. Please consider clarifying.

Comment: @Chemomechanics you are right option (1) must hold it's actually (3) which corresponds to (1) and (3) of Olber's paradox. About $dS = 0$, I disagree. $S = - k_B \sum_i  p_i \ln(e^{-\beta E_i})  $ where $p_i$ is the probability, $\beta$ is the beta factor and $E_i$ is the energy in a volume $V$. My temperature is cooling in a expanding volume.

Comment: The drop in entropy from cooling offsets the increase in entropy from the larger volume.

Comment: $a \propto 1/T$ and $V \propto a^3 $ in FLRW metric. I do think your claim holds.